# How to get the widget postion related to screen

Tags: python, pyqt

I want set a tooltip when a lineEdit is entered wrong data, and the tooltip is showed near the lineEdit. I try to using QToolTip.showText(). This need a position related to screen, but lineEdit.x(), lineEdit.y() or lineEdit.geometry() can only get the position related to their parent. So how can I get lineEdit position related to screen?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `lineEdit.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))` as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) point out:

> **QPoint QWidget::mapToGlobal(const QPoint &pos) const**
>
> Translates the widget coordinate pos to global screen coordinates. For
> example, mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)) would give the global coordinates of
> the top-left pixel of the widget.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I looking for, but I now get another promble, the positon 
that mapToGlobal returned not exactly match to the item. QToolTip.showText(self.mapToGlobal(self.pos()), ''), Is this wrong?

Comment: @Hisak Where in my code have I told you to use `self.pos()` ?

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstand it.

Comment: @Hisak Please read [ask] and review the [tour]